# Disintegration theorem: Is $\mu_y$ absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$ for $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-measures

I'm reading disintegration theorem from Tao's [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/254a-lecture-9-ergodicity/#more-252).

> **Disintegration theorem** Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $\mathcal X$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mu$ a Borel probability measure on $X$. Let $(Y, \mathcal Y)$ be a measurable space, $\pi:X\to Y$ a measurable map, and $\nu := f_\sharp \mu$ the push-forward of $\mu$ by through $f$. Then there is a collection $(\mu_y)_{y\in Y}$ of Borel probability measures on $X$ with the following properties.
>
> 1. For all bounded measurable $f:X\to \mathbb C$ and $\nu$-integrable $g:Y\to \mathbb C$,
>    $$
>    \int_X f (g\circ \pi) \mathrm d\mu = \int_Y \left(\int_X f\mathrm d\mu_y\right)g(y)\mathrm d\nu(y). \quad (\star)
>    $$
> 2. For all bounded measurable $g:Y\to \mathbb C$, for $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$,
>    $$
>    g\circ \pi=g(y) \quad \mu_y\text{-a.e.} \quad (\star\star)
>    $$

I'm interested in below question, i.e.,

> Is $\mu_y$ absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$ for $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$?

If YES, then

- (1.) can be extended to $\mu$-essentially bounded and measurable $f$.
- (2.) can be extended to $\nu$-integrable $g$.

Could you elaborate on my question? Thank you so much!

Below is my failed attempt in which I could **not** prove that $\mathcal H_y$ is closed under complement.

---

Let $(B_n)$ be a countable base of the metric topology of $X$. Then $\mathcal X$ is generated by $(B_n)$. Let
$$
\mathcal H_y := \{B \in \mathcal X \mid \mu(B) = 0 \implies \mu_y (B)=0\}
$$

Let $f = 1_{B_n}$ and $g = 1$ with $\mu(B_n)=0$. By (1.),
$$
0 = \int_Y \mu_y (B_n) \mathrm d \nu (y).
$$

Then $\mu_y (B_n) = 0$ $\nu$-a.e. Because $(B_n)$ is countable, there is a $\nu$-null set $N \in \mathcal Y$ such that
$$
\mu_y (B_n) = 0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N, \forall y \in N^c := Y \setminus N.
$$

This means for each $y \in N^c$, we have $(B_n) \subset \mathcal H_y$. To prove that for each $y \in N^c$, $\mu_y \ll \mu$ we need to prove $\mathcal H_y = \mathcal X$.   So it suffices to prove $\mathcal H_y$ is a $\sigma$-algebra for each $y \in N^c$. Clearly, $\emptyset \in \mathcal H_y$. Let $(H_n) \subset \mathcal H_y$ and $H := \bigcup_n H_n$. If $\mu(H)=0$ then $\mu(H_n)=0$ and thus $\mu_y (H_n)=0$ for all $n$. As such, $\mu_y (H) \le \sum_n \mu_y (H_n)=0$. Hence $H \in \mathcal H_y$ and thus $\mathcal H_y$ is closed under countable union. Let's prove that $\mathcal H_y$ is closed under complement. Let $H \in \mathcal H_y$ such that $\mu(H^c)=0$. Then $\mu(H)=1$ and $\mu_y (H^c) = 1-\mu_y(H)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $X=Y=[0,1]$ with the Borel sets, $\mu$ the uniform distribution, and $\pi$ the identity given by $\pi(x)=x$. Then $\nu$ is again the uniform distribution and $\mu_y=\delta_y$ (the point mass at $y$) for $\mu$-almost all $y\in Y$.

To see this, note that we have

$$\int f (g\circ \pi)~\mathrm d\mu =\int fg~\mathrm d\mu= \int f(x) g(x) ~\mathrm d\mu(x) =
\int \left(\int f~\mathrm d\delta_x\right)g(x)~\mathrm d\nu(x).$$
Since the $\mu_y$ are uniquely defined up to a $\nu$-null set (also stated at Tao's blog), we must have $\mu_y=\delta_y$ for $\nu$-almost all $y\in Y$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!